# Thinking about structurize large vuex application with submodules, how do it right?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

i'm workin on large vue application.
And, i have a lot of modules: organizations, users, etc.
At the moment i'm thinking on structure of large modules.

Please, help me making it's right and scalable.

For example.

activeOrganizationId - it's global variable, which affect at all application.

Organizations list - it's global variable with all organizations.
it's using in main navigation and etc.

OrganizationsListPage - it's table with organizations,
filters and etc CRUD functionality.

So. 
activeOrganizationId and module list - global .
pages.list - not global, it's OrganizationsListPage .

`// vuex Module organizations.
organizations: {
    state: {
        activeOrganizationId: '' // global app value
    },
    modules: {
        list: {
            // global organizations list
            state: {}
        },
        pages: {
            modules: {
                list: {
                    // lazy-load module for organizations list page
                    // registered in beforeCreate, unregistered in destroyed hooks
                    state: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`